# Sails raw query populate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, populate

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var userQueryAsync = Promise.promisify(Article.query);
userQueryAsync("SELECT article.slug, article.title, __user.name AS user___name, __user.phone AS user___phone FROM article JOIN user AS __user ON __user.id = article.user")
  .then(function(article) {
    var parsed = new Article._model(article);
    console.log(parsed);
});
```

I would like to create model objects thanks to a raw query in Sails.

Data I retrieve with the code above is :

```
{ '0':
  { 
    slug: 'article-1',
    title: 'Article 1',
    user: 1,
    user___name: 'Cainzer',
    user___phone: '0000000' 
  } 
}
```

I wish :

```
{ '0':
  { 
    slug: 'article-1',
    title: 'Article 1',
    user: {
      name: 'Cainzer',
      phone: '0000000' 
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a way to do it without looping ?

I know that I could do it easily with Article.find().populate("user"), but I'm showing you a simple example to make it work and apply solution on a more tricky situation.
I'm forced to use a raw query because Waterline doesn't implement WHERE clause in populate() yet with MySQL.

Comment: there is a solution to this, but it requires using the mysql package directly rather than using the sails-mysql wrapper. If that will work for you, I can post an answer.

Comment: I guess it would be cleaner to create a quick function myself, which will do the job. What do you think ?

Comment: Are you running many of these complex queries as part of your setup?

Comment: I think I will use many complex queries but only with one model, which is Article in this case.

Comment: In that case you could do what you mentioned and write a function, maybe something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412381/nodejs-join-query-formatting-json-output). Alternatively, you could go down the mysql package route. If you do, then you could use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql-nesting) package and to turn on nested formatting.